# IF EXISTS and multiple SELECT statements

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm relatively new to SQL.

I'm trying to get a SELECT statement to run only if another SELECT statement returns some results.

I wrote something like this:

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
IF EXISTS
(SELECT column1, column2 FROM table1 WHERE condition)
THEN
(SELECT column2, column3 FROM table2 WHERE condition);
END IF;
END
$$
```

I'm guessing that the issue here is that "IF EXISTS ... THEN" has to be followed by a a table modifier action, and not by a SELECT statement. Is that correct?

The purpose, as I'm dealing with a fairly large dataset, is to run the second statement only if the first one returns anything.

Would WHERE EXISTS be a better option?

Answer (score 0):

Look into case statements. I prefer WHERE value IS NOT NULL myself.

Comment: Thanks Babno. I've already looked into CASE WHEN statements, but I guess I should try again then. The issue for me is that i would like to have 2 separate statements, the second one ONLY running if the first one returns something.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your approach.  If you want a single query:

```
SELECT column2, column3
FROM table2
WHERE condition AND
      EXISTS (SELECT column1, column2 FROM table1 WHERE condition);
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon! So, I take it that WHERE EXISTS in this case works in a similar fashion? The query I wrote in my original post won't work unfortunately...

Comment: @Louloumonkey . . . I would argue that if this runs and does what you want, then it is a better option.